# Nonlinear ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I've in second-year, taking a course on differential equations. We've learned about integrating factors, different classifications, substitutions, etc. I think I have a hold on lots of this stuff so far but this one problem is stuck in my teeth and it's driving me crazy. It looks simple enough but Maple spits out a big ugly logarithmic equation with an arctan term, and I don't know where to begin:

$x^2\,dx + (xy + x^2)\,dy = 0$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{x^{2}}{xy+x^{2}} = -\frac{1}{\frac{y}{x} + 1}.
$$
using the transform $z = y/x$ yields 
$$
x\frac{dz}{dx} + z = - \frac{1}{z+1}.
$$
This is separable and therefore can be solved.

To complete the problem
$$
\int \frac{(z+1)}{z(z+1)+1}dz = -\int \frac{1}{x} = -\mathrm{ln}(x) + C
$$
now we shall concentrate on the lhs
$$
\frac{(z+1)}{z(z+1)+1} = \frac{4}{3}\frac{(z+1)}{\left(\frac{z+\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{3/4}}\right)^{2}+1}. 
$$
Using a change of variable $u = \frac{z+\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}}$ leads to
$$
\frac{4}{3}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}u+\frac{1}{2}}{u^{2}+1}= \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\frac{u+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}{u^{2}+1}
$$
after all that re-arranging we can sub back into the integral. 
$$
\int \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\frac{u+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}{u^{2}+1}\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}du = -\mathrm{ln}(x) + C
$$
we can split the integral on the lhs as 
$$
\int \frac{u}{u^{2}+1} du + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int \frac{1}{u^{2}+1}du  
$$
The terms above evaluates to terms in the brackets below
$$
\left[\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{ln}\left(u^{2}+1\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\mathrm{arctan}(u) \right] = -\mathrm{ln}(x) + C
$$

$$
u = \frac{1}{x}\frac{2y+x}{\sqrt{3}}
$$
transforming back
$$
\left[\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{ln}\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\frac{2y+x}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^{2}+1\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\mathrm{arctan}\left(\frac{1}{x}\frac{2y+x}{\sqrt{3}}\right) \right] = -\mathrm{ln}(x) + C
$$

which if we expand the log argument yields

$$
\left(\frac{1}{x}\frac{2y+x}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^{2}+1 = \frac{4y^{2} + 4xy + x^{2} + 3x^{2}}{3x^{2}} = \frac{4}{3}\frac{y^{2} + xy + y^{2}}{x^{2}}
$$
which if we take the logarithm of 
$$
\mathrm{ln}\left(\frac{4}{3}\right) + \mathrm{ln}\left(\frac{y^{2} + xy + y^{2}}{x^{2}}\right)
$$
we can sub back into the solution equation and take the constant logarithm into the constant C, we finally reach 
$$
\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{ln}\left(\frac{y^{2} + xy + y^{2}}{x^{2}}\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\mathrm{arctan}\left(\frac{1}{x}\frac{2y+x}{\sqrt{3}}\right)  = -\mathrm{ln}(x) + C
$$
was this close to what you got?

Comment: In your fourth equation, you go from having a $z^2$ term in the denominator to only having a $z$ term.

Comment: @Arkamis oops!! thank you.

Comment: You're the best =)

Comment: @user126291 no problem. I am glad to help